# My form is submitting multiple database entries and I don't want it to

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, multiple-instances

I have a simple html form and a php file to execute a database insertion. The problem I am having is that when I press the submit button, my database table receives 3 copies of the same submission and I only need one. Below is the code.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <form action="demo.php" method="post">
        <p>
            Input 1: <input type="text" name="input1" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </form>
</html>
```

php:

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'phpmyadminName');
define('DB_USER', 'phpmyadminUser');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected){
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value = $_POST['input1'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO demo (input1) VALUES ('$values')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

The DB_NAME, DB_USER, and DB_PASSWORD have all been changed for obvious reasons, but the code does work.

It just submits too many copies of the form data to the database table. Way back when I was in school, I had this issue, but it seemed like the problem was on the server's end and not our code. The server used here is mine and I do have full control over it. If the server is the issue at fault, I need help correcting that (as I am doing this to learn how to admin these tools, I do not know much more than basic level administration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kenneth, the code you have provided here honestly needs some work. First of all, please don't use the `mysql` API anymore. It's deprecated, will no longer be supported in future PHP versions, and is insecure. For all database operations use the `mysqli` or `PDO` API's, preferrably with prepared statements.
Secondly, do not ever `INSERT` `$_POST` or `$_GET` variables directly into the database without validating/sanitizing them first as someone could delete your data or even worse your whole database. PHP has numerous functions to make this very easy such as [ctype](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php) depending on the data type.

Maybe try something like this in your code:

```
if (!empty($_POST['input1'])) { //checks if data was received//
    $value = $_POST['input1'];
    mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO demo (input1) VALUES ('$value')";
} else {
    echo "form was not received";
    exit;
}
```

I also noticed that your variable names were different, which is corrected above.

EDIT :
Mistakenly used wrong syntax for PHP ctype function.

Comment: Looking into ctype. Trying the code as is and I get the 'unexpected values' error. I'll post an update when I hash that issue out. Thanks for you valuable insight.

Comment: Ok, posted this on the wrong reply a second ago, but I figured out my error problem. Turns out the string I typed caused the error. I typed the phrase "test 1" and the space threw the error at me like a jug of water on a fire. this code does work as intended.

Comment: I see, the information above was a generic recommendation since I didn't know what type of data you're processing. Seems like just checking if it's empty then using a prepared statement should be fine since all input will be escaped. In this case, `mysql_real_escape_string` is what you would want to use before inserting into database. I will update my answer.

Comment: I tried the updated version. It works, but the field data comes up blank. I will gander a guess that it's the collation causing the issue there.

Comment: Could possibly be the charset, may need to set it.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the POST input value in the variable named `$value` and in query you are sending `$values`

I have corrected the code.

Can you please try the below code

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'phpmyadminName');
define('DB_USER', 'phpmyadminUser');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected){
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$value = $_POST['input1'];
if($value!=''){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO demo (input1) VALUES ('".$value."')";
}

if (!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: @Kenneth Thanks for the reply happy to help you
If the issue is fixed please accept the answer so that the question is not categorized in unanswered :)

Answer (score 0):

Below is correct code for the issue. I have checked that when you refresh your page it will create new blank entry in database and also the variable name is wrong.

You have to check for the Request method. This

> $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'

will check the form method and it will prevent the blank entries in database.

```
 <?php
        define('DB_NAME', 'test');
        define('DB_USER', 'root');
        define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mysqldba');
        define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

        $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

        if (!$link){
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

        if (!$db_selected){
            die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
        }
        //Test for request method
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
            $value = $_POST['input1'];

            $sql = "INSERT INTO demo (input1) VALUES ('$value')";
            //echo $sql;die;
            if (!mysql_query($sql)){
                die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            }
        }
        mysql_close();
        ?>
```